# Useless prompt when trying to delete answered question?

Tags: bug, questions, vote-to-delete

If you try to delete an answered question, the site asks if you are sure about it. However, even if you click yes, it will just tell you that you can't delete it because it's an answered question. Why is there a prompt in the first place if it can't be deleted anyway?

Comment: It *can* be when a question have one answer which has a score of <1, the message is just misleading.

Comment: ...and diamond Moderators can delete a question regardless of the state of any of its answers.

Answer (score 1):

The message is a bit baffling really - it comes to ask you to reconsider the decision to delete the question if their is already an answer, but doesn't take into account the score of the answer.

I propose the 2 checks (dialog and red box ones) be replaced by one check that says:

- if highest voted answer < 1 then say 'are you sure you want to delete' (y/n)
- else (if) highest voted answer > 0 then say 'you cannot delete this question because it has an upvoted answer' (ok) or messages to that affect
- else (if) user is mod then say 'are you sure you want to delete' (y/n)